# How to set label based on toggle switch value

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I use Bootstrap 5 and I wand to use a switch-toggle.

How to set Label based on Switch value.

This does not work:

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="status">
  <script>
   if ($('#status').val() == 1) {
      <label for="site_state" class="form-check-label">Aktif</label>
   } else {
      <label for="site_state" class="form-check-label">Tidak Aktif</label>
   }
   </script>
</div>
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Use jQuery's `change` event to listen for changes on the checkbox. When the checkbox changes, you can check its `checked` property to determine whether it's checked or not and then update the label accordingly.

```html
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="status">
  <label for="status" class="form-check-label" id="statusLabel">Tidak Aktif</label>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#status').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $('#statusLabel').text('Aktif');
    } else {
      $('#statusLabel').text('Tidak Aktif');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```